# magento get Configurable attributes in attribute set

Tags: magento, attributes, configurable

How can I get all configurable attributes in attribute set?

I was looping all the attribute set then I want to display only its configurable attribute.

Comment: where do you want to do this?  depending on where (product page? cart? checkout?) there are different methods.

Comment: @jdu - in the admin page

Comment: admin page? can you provide more info about your goal? not sure I understand enough to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get an attribute collection and filter it (based on the attribute set) - this would return you all attributes in the specified set that are configurable.

```
$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
->setAttributeSetFilter($attributeSetId)
->addFieldToFilter("is_configurable", array("eq", "1"))
->getItems();
```

Comment: doesn't work, it returns all the attributes in the attribute set even if the attribute is not configurable

Answer (score 1):

[image: There are three conditions for a configurable attribute]

I assume that by configurable attributes, you actually mean attributes that can be used to create a configurable product. Douglas Radburn's answer is the right way to do this, it's only missing two more filters. As you can see in the picture above, there are three conditions for using an attribute to create a configurable product. Using the image's message as reference, we can construct the following collection.

```
$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel("catalog/product_attribute_collection")
->setAttributeSetFilter($attributeSetId)
->addFieldToFilter("frontend_input", "select")
->addFieldToFilter("is_configurable", "1")
->addFieldToFilter("is_global", "1");
```

Comment: Good Answer @Aapo

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$objAttributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
->addFieldToFilter("is_configurable", array("1"))
->getItems();
```